# How to clear react input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I am adding the `setNewItem('');` to clear the input form after it has been added to my list but when I submit a new item to my list, it does not clear my input form, any ideas why?

**This function handles my items being submitted**

```js
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!newItem) return;
    addItem(newItem)
    setNewItem('');
  }
```

Comment: Please show us the `<input>`

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to the input tag

```
<input value={newItem} />
```